# Bind HashSet to DataGridView DataSource C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datagridview, datasource

I am newbie I have tried to bind simply `HashSet` as `DataSource` of DataGridView, but still has any item in `GridView`

```
     dataGridViewBookList.DataSource = null;
     dataGridViewBookList.DataSource = bookContainer;
```

Creating hash set

```
   bookContainer = new HashSet<BookModel>();
   dataGridViewBookList.DataSource = bookContainer;
```

BookModel class

```
 class BookModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public uint Year { get; set; }
        public string Series { get; set; }
        public string Pulbisher { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public uint PagesCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Please help to bind hash set to GridView. Sorry for this question I am newbie in C#.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 var book = new BookModel//fill it with your data
        {
            Author = "a",
            Language = "l",
            Name = "n",
            PagesCount = 0,
            Pulbisher = "p",
            Series = "s",
            Year = 1990
        };
        var list=new List<BookModel>();
        list.Add(book);
        var bookContainer = new HashSet<BookModel>(list);//you have to pass list to HashSet constructor

        dataGridViewBookList.DataSource = bookContainer.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try ToList() for bookContainer